# static_pointer_cast for weak_ptr

Tags: c++11, weak-ptr

In c++0x, there is a std::static_pointer_cast for std::shared_ptr, but there is no equivalent method for std::weak_ptr. Is this intentional, or an oversight? If an oversight, how would I define an appropriate function?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This ought to do it for you:

```
template<class T, class U>
std::weak_ptr<T>
static_pointer_cast(std::weak_ptr<U> const& r)
{
    return std::static_pointer_cast<T>(std::shared_ptr<U>(r));
}
```

This will throw an exception if the weak_ptr has expired.  If you would rather get a null weak_ptr, then use `r.lock()` instead.

Comment: Are you aware of the history of this at all? Given how trivial this was to write, I wonder why the standards committee didn't include it.

Comment: I just scanned the standards docs, and it looks to me like no one ever proposed it.  I also can't find a record of it being asked for or proposed on boost (the original source of std::weak_ptr).  Perhaps the reason is that it is trivial to write, and non-trivial to pick the proper policy (throw or null).  And providing two functions (one for each policy) is sub-optimal because `static_pointer_cast` is meant to be a generic name, usable in code where the pointer type is generic.

Comment: IMO, this should be in the standard. And without the `lock()`. Technically, I believe that except for `dynamic_cast`, is no reason one needs to `lock()` a `weak_ptr` before casting it. The same way there is no need to lock it to move, copy or to upcast. The data is exactly the same, only the weak_ptr type changes.

Answer (score 6):

Howard's version is correct, but in many cases it makes sense to simply pass weakptr.lock() as parameter to std::static_pointer_cast:

```
std::weak_ptr<A> a = ...;  
std::weak_ptr<B> b = std::static_pointer_cast<B>(a.lock());
```

This syntax explicitly shows what is going on, and makes code easy to read.

Comment: Seems like there's a bug here. Since the a.lock() is a temporary the underlying pointer could be deleted while the code subsequent to this is still using b.  -- Actually after reading static_pointer_cast docs again, I'm wrong. It returns a shared pointer that will shares with a's underlying shared pointer.

Comment: This code works, however it involves expensive runtime atomic operations, while static_pointer_cast is always a free operation.

Comment: @aberaud: Yes! I do not see why there is no `static_pointer_cast` for `weak_ptr`. Implementation is trivial and the cast could be made at compile time. We should be able to cast a `weak_ptr` even if it is invalid!!!

Answer (score 3):

The omission is intentional because despite it's name, std::weak_ptr is not a pointer type and does not provide pointer interface (operator ->, operator *, static_pointer_cast, etc.).

Comment: This does not justify anything! The `std::static_pointer_cast` is used to cast the pointer type of the data. The control data is the same, everything is the same, but when you `lock()` it, you expect it to return you a `shared_ptr<C>` and not a `shared_ptr<A>`. Just what it does to `shared_ptr`, but only after you `lock()` it. Casting a `weak_ptr` is as legitimate as casting a `shared_ptr`. And one should not be forced to `lock()` it in order to cast. Of course, the exception would be a `dynamic_cast`, that needs the real object to do the math.